# How to exit Mappa/Leaflet div after clicking into it

Tags: javascript, dom, leaflet, maps, dom-events

I've used Mappa to create a Leaflet map overlay as shown in the code and gif below.

After clicking into the Map viz menu item, it seems that the overlay (the + and - zoom buttons and the word leaflet on the bottom right) remain perpetually. After clicking on another menu item and back into Map viz, a second map is created as a tile at the bottom of the original canvas. This repeats itself whenever I click on another menu item and click back into Map viz.

[image]

Here's the code I used to create the map canvas:

```
  this.setup = function () {
    // Create canvas for map
    this.mapCanvas = select('#app');
    this.m = createCanvas(this.layout.plotWidth(), this.layout.plotHeight());
    this.m.parent('worldmap');
    this.myMap = mappa.tileMap(options);
    this.myMap.overlay(this.m);
  };
```

It relates to the following in `index.html`:

```
   <body>
    <div id="app" class="container">
      <ul id="visuals-menu"></ul>
      <ul id="worldmap"></ul>
    </div>    
    </div>
  </body>
```

Using Inspect Element, I see that when I click on any menu item *without* first clicking on Map viz, `defaultCanvas0` is highlighted.

[image]

But after clicking into Map viz, the `worldmap` div seems to be perpetually chosen, even after I click on other menu items. Is there a way to cleanly exit the Mappa/Leaflet map or `worldmap` div after I exit from it? I've tried `clear()`, `remove()` but haven't gotten any luck. Please let me know if I should paste other parts of the code. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I would look into where `setup` is getting called - it seems like its getting called every time you click 'Map viz', but there is never any cleanup function when you click away from 'Map viz', so certain elements remain, and the map also draws again with every click.  This seems like a very specific-scenario type bug.  Without a living copy of the code, or some reproducible example of the bug, It may be impossible for us to debug this.

Comment: Thanks @SethLutske, could I ask what might typically be used as a cleanup function? Mappa says `tilemap()` has to be called within `setup()` which I guess is the source of the problem: https://mappa.js.org/docs/api-overlay.html

Comment: Without a reproducible example, we can't help.